# Emacs - Python completion in inferior shell with partially typed command

Tags: python, shell, emacs, elpy

A feature that I tend to use quite often in the ipython shell is auto-completion of partially typed command from the history. At the repl, one can type only the first few letters of the command and hit the <kbd>up</kbd> to find in the command history the last executed command that begin with the partially typed string.

Is this feature available in emacs? by pressing <kbd>C-up</kbd>, the python command history can be recalled, but it does not use the partially typed command?

Comment: `M-r`, which is short for `M-x comint-history-isearch-backward-regexp` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @unutbu just tried it... well, it kind of works, maybe not as quick as the behaviour of the normal ipython shell... whould you know what's the command that is boud to C^ArrowUp?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `C^ArrowUp` (perhaps because I don't use elpy?). But you should be able to find out what function it is bound to by pressing `C-h k` `C^ArrowUp`. Or, you can peruse `C-h b`, which shows all the key bindings understood by the current buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get completion for partially typed commands using `comint-previous-matching-input-from-input` and `comint-next-matching-input-from-input`.

By default they are bind to  <kbd>C-c M-r</kbd> and <kbd>C-c M-s</kbd>.

If you have typed  `l = 1` and now you can type`l` and press <kbd>C-c M-r</kbd>  to get previous completion.

If you dont  want  to use <kbd>C-c M-r</kbd> and like to  use up arrow,  you put this  code in your  config.

```
(eval-after-load 'comint
    '(progn      
         (define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "<up>") 
            #'comint-previous-matching-input-from-input)
         (define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "<down>")
            #'comint-next-matching-input-from-input)))
```

Now you can use <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> arrows for it.

Comment: Yes! thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed!